# Combining 2 SPF records with 2 different host names

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I have 2 spf records I need to combine.

**1st spf record is:**
Host: front-mail Value: v=spf1 include:sendgrid.net ~all

**2nd spf record is:**
Host: @ Value: v = spf1 include:zoho.jp ~all

I've tried to combine them as:
Host: @ Value: v=spf1 include:sendgrid.net include:zoho.jp ~all

But it seems like this doesn't work, because the host name for the 1st spf record is front-mail. Any tips on combining them into 1 spf record?

Comment: Try using a builder, looks like you format is correct: v=spf1 include:zoho.jp include:sendgrid.net ~all

Answer (score 1):

Usually when the host field has a value in the spf record it's for a subdomain. So that means that sendgrid (sendgrid is an service for outbound email) was being used for a subdomain, with changing the spf record that could also means that sendgrid needs be updated in terms of verification,or settings on their end. because the domain name will be different (root domain instead of subdomain).