# Combining 2 Hosts for TXT SPF Records

Tags: spf, txt-record

[Related to that question](https://serverfault.com/q/1151892/256639) from [@Jaeho Lee](https://serverfault.com/users/1071569/jaeho-lee), Someone figured out a solution for the Host issue when you combined the two spf records? I am having the same issue; if so, can someone please advise?

I have combined 2 spf records, as listed below in #3.  However, I receive an error because I am unsure how to list 2 Hosts in the TXT record. Does anyone know how to address this, any solution?

1. v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
2. v=spf1 include:sendgrid.net ~all
3. v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.net ~all

How do I include both Hosts names for google and sendgrid? Any information would be helpful. Thx!

Comment: Those are for the same domain? Not that sendgrid is for subdomain.domain.com and Google is for domain.com

Comment: Your syntax is correct, a SPF record can have multiple include statements.

Comment: Google for google workspace for our domain, sendgrid is to send via our CRM.  The two Hosts are: @ and em8676, but I receive an error message when trying to list both hosts in the txt record.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple include directives in an SPF record are allowed, so `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.net ~all`   is valid syntax and should exactly do what you intend.

But with records containing `include:` directives the receiver will quite easily run into the following limit set in [RFC 4408 §10.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408.html#section-10.1)

> SPF implementations MUST limit the number of mechanisms and modifiers
> that do DNS lookups to at most 10 per SPF check, including any
> lookups caused by the use of the "include" mechanism or the
> "redirect" modifier

Both the Sendgrid and Google SPF records each contain additional `include:` directives so you might be reaching that limit.

For illustration:

```
_spf.google.com.    300 IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all"
```

That triggers 3 additional lookups in addition to the lookup for `_spf.google.com.`

and

```
sendgrid.net.       90  IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:167.89.0.0/17 ip4:208.117.48.0/20 ip4:50.31.32.0/19 ip4:198.37.144.0/20 ip4:198.21.0.0/21 ip4:192.254.112.0/20 ip4:168.245.0.0/17 ip4:149.72.0.0/16 ip4:159.183.0.0/16 include:ab.sendgrid.net ~all"
```

also triggers an additional lookup.

Comment: As an aside, I use this site to check SPF records. It shows the entire SPF lookup "tree" including nested lookups. - https://easydmarc.com/tools/spf-lookup

Comment: Thank you @HBruijn